When it comes to games, is the the term "rigged" synonymous with "unfair"?
I was having a conversation about different types of dice, weighted and intransitive, many sided, and so on, and the question popped in my head. Would every type of rigged game, necessarily be unfair? (considering that inequality in the players position or different viable strategies might be asymmetric but still a worthwhile game to play)

"Rigged" is more than unfair.  Something like "intensionally unfair".

A dice game in which players win if they roll a double (two ones, two twos, two threes, two fours, two fives, or two sixes) but lose if they roll any other combination is not fair because the odds are stacked against them. A dice game in which the dice have been altered in such a way that they always come up one four and one three is rigged because they guarantee that whoever is betting against a seven is going to lose every time. Players can win an unfair game every now and then through unusually good luck; players can't win a game that is rigged against them.

This is a philosophical question about the nature of fairness. (If someone was cheating you might rig the game so they lose. Is that fair? Probably it depends.)

Could you possible link the question to some evidence about actual usage of the two words by reference, for example to dictionaries?  Otherwise the question seems to be 'off topic'.

@tuffY In the US the words rigged and fair are active in political discourse in ways dictionaries, always backward-looking, may be poor guides. So no way this is off-topic.

@Sven Yargs I find your comparison about rigging a game against a cheater intriguing, for it asks whether it is possible to design a rigged game against cheaters and therefore making it more fair to "proper" players. In a more modern sense of games, like World of Warcraft, if the developers included mechanics in the software that track character behaviour that helped find cheaters, like bots say, without telling the players, would it be considered fair/just/rigged? (Aside, unequal probabilities isn't most of the time considered unfair, if the winnings are at least in accordance to the odds)

Related.

@Xanne:  The American dictionary, Merriam Webster, gives a clear pair of definitions, which is consistent with the distinction which you draw.  'Rigging' in the world of naval and engineering activity is a legitimate and necessary activity, while in the context of competitive games and sports, it is unfair and, indeed, dishonest.  There is no reason not to support an answer by referring to a dictionary or English grammar book.

Saying that a game is rigged implies that its workings have been intentionally modified by someone, to change the players' chances of winning, without that being disclosed to all the players. The players who don't know about the modification agree to play under the assumption that the game works the usual way, and their agreement to play is thus based on a deception. That deception renders a rigged game unfair.
The interesting question is whether a game can be unfair without being rigged. If the game is a pure game of chance, it is difficult to see how that could be: for the games of chance, being rigged thus coincides with being unfair.
Consider, however, a game that is not a pure game of chance. Suppose that A and B agree to play that game, and that A is somebody who has just learnt the game while B is a highly skilled, highly experienced player. Suppose, moreover, that B deceives A about that, pretending to be a novice, just like A; A agrees to play the game naively believing to be facing someone of similar skills and experience. The ensuing game would be unfair to A, because A's agreement to play is based on B's deception. It would, however, be wrong to say that the game is rigged. This is because rigging always involves manipulation of the workings of the game (e.g. loading the dice), while in this case the unfairness is due to something else.

A game could be unfair by accident (e.g. some cards had been lost from a deck that favored one player) or it could be unfair because there was a misunderstanding by both sides - for example playing the Monty Hall game where both players thought the odds were 50-50.

A rigged game involves manipulation of its outcome.
Certain games, such as casino-based games, are intentionally calibrated to be mathematically in the favor of the house. We can interpret unfairness in scenarios such as these in 2 ways:

On the surface, the odds are against the player, therefore it seems unfair.


However, given the nature of gambling, and given that the game is not rigged beyond its legal limit, the game technically does not possess any elements of deception.

To answer your question, if a game is rigged beyond what is permissible, the game would be considered to be deceptive and thus unfair to the parties adversely affected by this.

I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted, although I suspect that the downvoter was reacting negatively to the fact that the poster has simply made a reasonable argument rather than marshaling third-party authority for it. But given that the poster is a newcomer to EL&U, it might have been more helpful (as well as more courteous) to have explained the thinking behind the downvote than to have done a drive-by. In any case, AscenderVI, I hope that the initial downvote doesn't discourage you from contributing to this site—but note, too, that citing published authority is highly valued here.

Thank you very much for your feedback!
